# CaptureDevice.CheckForRecordingDeviceAsync() always returns false

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to run [this project](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication/cs/Scenario2_VideoChat.xaml.cs) but when I ran it, it said

```
A machine with a camera and a microphone is required to run this sample.
```

since it uses `var cameraFound = await CaptureDevice.CheckForRecordingDeviceAsync();`.

So, I wonder why does this occur? My computer has both WebCam and microphone and they all work fine.

How should I solve this?

I am happy to add more information but this is pretty much what I've known so far.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried this sample in other machines? This sample works well in my side. In method it used `await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);`  to find all  video capture devices. It should be able to find your WebCam.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I asked my friend to test on her computer and it worked fine. So, I am not sure what's wrong with mine. I can use webcam and microphone on other services like Skype perfectly. This confuses me.